# Python permutation

Tags: python

How would I accomplish the following in python:

```
first = ['John', 'David', 'Sarah']
last = ['Smith', 'Jones']

combined = ['John Smith', 'John Jones', 'David Smith', 'David Jones', 'Sarah Smith', 'Sarah Jones']
```

Is there a method to combine all permutations?

Comment: You could code a permutation generator yourself in any* language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
combined = [f + ' ' + l for f, l in itertools.product(first, last)]
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if there is a more elegant solution, but this should work:

`[x + " " + y for x in first for y in last]`

Answer (score 4):

`product` from `itertools` will do the trick.

```
product(first, last)
```

will give return a generator with all possible combinations of `first` and `last`. After that, all you need to do is concatenate the first and last names. You can do this in one expression:

```
combined = [" ".join(pair) for pair in product(first, last)]
```

It's also possible to do this with string concatenation:

```
combined = [pair[0] + " " + pair[1] for pair in product(first, last)]
```

This method is slower though, as the concatenation done in the interpreter. It's always recommended to use the `"".join()` method as this code is executed in C.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any python utility method for this, however following will achieve the same:

```
def permutations(first, second):
  result = []
  for i in range(len(first)):
    for j in range(len(second)):
      result.append(first[i] + ' ' + second[j])
  return result
```

Comment: Your Python knowledge is a little out of date, you need a refresher. Read and learn from the other posts, esp. the one from Joel Cornett. itertools.product handles the for-loop nesting, and list comprehensions are better than explicit appending as your code does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I realized the same after reading other answers, i have gone throgh the itertools and list comprehensions now.