# Python code to pick out all possible permutations of a n-digit number using x-y numbers only?

Tags: python, python-2.7, permutation

```
__author__ = 'Mark'
import itertools

def power(num, x=1):
  result = 1;
  for x in range(x):
    result = result * num
  return result
print power(4,7)

count = 0
for subset in itertools.product('0123456', repeat = 4):
     print(subset)
     count +=1
     print count
```

I need to enumerate all possible permutation of a 4-digit number using 0-6 only with repetition.

Comment: where is your attempts?

Comment: @user5667787 Have a look at the `itertools` module in python - https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html & try to solve the question. If you are still facing issues then you can reach out. Without an attempt to solve the problem the SO community would not help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python permutation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369300/python-permutation)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at product, permutations, combinations, combinations_wit_replacement functions from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).